# Remove unwanted permissions from Expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play

I developed an Expo app (managed) and generated the Android binary using EAS. After submitting the binary for internal testing, I see many **dangerous unwanted permissions** on the Google Play store.

[image: unwanted permissions on Google Play store]

The worse ones are "Camera: take pictures" and "Microphone: record audio." These scare away anyone concerned with privacy.

My app doesn't access the camera or the microphone, and I have no idea how these permissions got there.

I found questions related to React-Native and Android development, and their solution is to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml`. This solution is not compatible with my case, a Managed Expo environment. And no, I'm not ejecting the app.

*PS: There are similar questions to this, but none related to Managed Expo environments - they are all about Android or React Native. Not the same thing.*

Comment: Where is this screen shot from? I can't find what permissions my app is requesting.

Comment: @pors The screenshot is from Google Play. I built the app with the `eas` command, publish the binary to Google Play (as internal testing, not visible to the general public), and then I could see my app on Google Play, which shows the permissions info.

Comment: Ah yes! It doesn't show up in the Play app on android, but it does on the web play store. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short answer:

On SDK 45+, use `blockedPermissions` to remove unwanted permissions:

```json
"android": {
  // ...
  "blockedPermissions": [
    "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
    "android.permission.CAMERA"
  ]
}
```

On SDK 44-, use `permissions: []`. This will **not work on EAS builds** though, you have to use Classic builds (retired in Jan 2023):

```json
"android": {
  // ...
  "permissions": []
}
```

---

### Long Answer

It happens that Expo automatically includes lots of permissions by default: camera access, microphone recording, read and write external storage, etc.

In the past, with Clasic Builds (retired in Jan 2023), the solution was to include a `permissions` key on `app.json` to remove permissions.

For example, to remove them all, we used to do this: `"permissions": []`.

The Classic builds were replaced by EAS builds, and they changed the behavior of `permissions`.

On EAS builds, you have to use `blockedPermissions` instead. But this keyword is only available on SDK 45+.

[From Expo Github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8379#issuecomment-1130315857):

> The `permissions` key works differently in classic builds vs EAS Build. on EAS Build, `permissions` is just for adding permissions, it doesn't remove any. `blockedPermissions` is only supported on EAS Build and SDK 45+ also.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How can I actually see what permissions are requested for my app?

Comment: @pors They are on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. To get this file, you need to eject from Expo. If you don't want to eject, just do a copy of your folder and run eject on this copy.

Answer (score 1):

To use ONLY the following minimum necessary permissions and none of the extras supported by Expo in a default managed app, set permissions to []. The minimum necessary permissions do not require a Privacy Policy when uploading to Google Play Store and are: • receive data from Internet • view network connections • full network access • change your audio settings • prevent device from sleeping To use ALL permissions supported by Expo by default, do not specify the permissions key. To use the minimum necessary permissions ALONG with certain additional permissions, specify those extras in permissions, e.g.
[ "CAMERA", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" ].

Thats why you have extra permissions, you can read about it [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions)

Comment: Thanks, Mehdi. I added `permissions: []` to my `app.json#expo.android`, compiled it again, but still shows `CAMERA` and `RECORD_AUDIO` permissions. I even ran a `expo run:android` and looked into the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` and these permissions are still there. :/

Comment: I found a solution! I added `blockedPermissions` along with "permissions". It happens that some libraries ("expo-av" and "sentry-expo") were automatically adding these extra permissions. With "blockedPermissions" I was able to force Expo to remove them. Thanks again, Mehdi, for taking some time to help me with this.

Comment: oh, nice, thanks! and well done debugging! :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be a late answer. But can we also use this option as well.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="">

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
    tools:node="remove" />
```